# jqGrid - Group summary row is not part of rowdata object

Tags: jqgrid, grouping

I am using jqGrid (V 5.5.4). I am using the rowdata object to generate jQuery UI accordions with collapse and a custom pager, for mobile phone data display. My page contains grouping and summary rows. The summary rows do not have an id or jqGrid class by default and are not included in the rowdata object. I would like to include the summary row in it's correct position in the rowdata object. Summary rows in red below.

**Desktop Display**

[image]

**Mobile Display**

[image]

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is true and you can not get all the data including grouping summary rowss.
It important to note that summary grouping row has a class which name is **jqfoot**.

The header grouping row has id which is combination of some strings. For this purpose look at the [docs here](http://www.guriddo.net/documentation/guriddo/javascript/user-guide/grouping/#group-methods)

Since I find your requirement usefully, I will prepare a method which will return the grouped data with headers and footers.

I will notify you about this in the next days.

Comment: That is awesome. I have been 'bonking' on this issue for a week now and am working on a server side grouping solution without jqGrid grouping summary rows, but your grouping is so much more elegant for the desktop grid. I have added <div>'s with classes to the summaryTpl: to help identify summary row values.  
Thanks